# Can I end a firebase callback in the callback itself?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know if there is any way to stop the callback inside the callback itself. I've tried using the ref.off() method to stop it like below, but it will still continue to run. Any suggestions?

```
ref.orderByChild('t').startAt(time.getTime()).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  const d = snapshot.val();
  const x = Math.round(d.x * 100).toString();
  const y = Math.round(d.y * 100).toString();
  if (that.selectedEnd && d.t > that.selectedEnd.getTime()) {
    snapshot.ref.off('child_added');
    console.log('STOP');
  } else {
    ....
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation for [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on):

> Returns function
>
> The provided callback function is returned unmodified. This is just
>   for convenience if you want to pass an inline function to on() but
>   store the callback function for later passing to off().

So, you can pass its return value to `off()`, called on the same Query object where you called `on()`:

```
const query = ref.orderByChild('t').startAt(time.getTime());
const listener = query.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    ...
    query.off('child_added', listener);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the fast response. But It gives an error on listener: Argument of type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventType'.
  Type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any' is not assignable to type '"child_removed"'.
Tried it like this: query.off('child_added', listener) but it's not working either.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the TypeScript bindings.  But this is the way you're supposed to do it, according to the API docs.